# Facing issue in sessionStorage Proxy implementation in Ext JS Grid view

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs, store, session-storage

I just created a Sencha fiddle wherein I have one panel with two grid views inside it. Both Grid views facilitates item selection from left to right and vice-versa. I'm trying to show the selected item from left grid view into right grid view. I'm using sessionStorage proxy to hold data while moving items from left to right grid view. I have to use sessionStorage because my requirement is to persist this selection across the pages.

Sencha fiddle link : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2j7u

Although, I'm not getting any error but my implementation is not working. Even the console logs show the correct selection data. But still I'm unable to populate the right grid view.

One thing I noticed is that in browser debugger under Applcation -> SessionStorage, my sessionStorage object is always null. Don't know why but on console it shows the data.

[Console logs from fiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4zAq.png)

[sessionStorage value from debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vLdw.png)

Any pointers would be highly appreciated!

On a side note, the same implementation was working fine with Ext JS 4.2. But I'm facing issue while migrating to Ext JS 6.5

Thanks,
Dhiraj

**Further troubleshooting:**

Further, I have updated the same fiddle and was successful to make it work further, by commenting out 'suspendEvents' and 'resumeEvents' for my right grid 'store' --> store2 and 'sessionStore' --> sessionStore2 in *tropos.selectDevices.addToSelect* method. Along-with this I figured out that  line 'store2.loadPage(1)' in *tropos.selectDevices.updateGridViews* method was clearing my grid on loading. I tried to avoid that using 'clearOnPageLoad' config setting for store to false. But it DIDN'T work so I commented this line to make it work. Now, although, it works but my main requirement of PRESERVING user selection is still not met because sessionStorage is still not working.

*Updated fiddle:* https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2j7u

Thanks,
Dhiraj

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your addToSelect :

```
example.selectDevices.addToSelect = function(storeObj){
    var addRecs = [], newRecs = [],
    store2 = Ext.getCmp('grid2').getStore();

    //********************  
    //I just comment all  *sessionStore2* references because is redundand,
    //store2 is the same as sessionStore2 
    //********************

    //sessionStore2 = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('currentlySelectedDevices');
    //store2.suspendEvents();
    //sessionStore2.suspendEvents();

    Ext.each(storeObj,function(record){
        var rec = record.copy();
        rec.phantom = true;
        addRecs.push(rec);
        newRecs.push(record.data.hid);
    });
    example.selectDevices.selectedDeviceIds = example.selectDevices.selectedDeviceIds.concat(newRecs);
    store2.add(addRecs);
    //store2.commitChanges();

    for(i=0; i < store2.data.items.length; i++) {
        console.log("addToSelect: Selected Device Serial [" + i + "] from STORE_2: " + store2.data.items[i].data.hid);
    }
    //sessionStore2.add(addRecs);

    //for(j=0; j < sessionStore2.data.items.length; j++) {
    //    console.log("addToSelect: Selected Device Serial [" + j + "] from SESSION_STORAGE_2: " + sessionStore2.data.items[j].data.hid);
    //}
    //sessionStore2.sync();

    store2.sync();
    //sessionStore2.resumeEvents();

    example.selectDevices.updateGridViews();
};
```

**EDIT:** You have to mark the record as phantom = true in order the sync work properly

Comment: @Fabrio : Thanks for the attempt. As expected it is working but this is not what I can use because I cannot remove sessionStorage altogether. For example, if a user does some device selection and CLOSE the panel without submit action. Now when he tries to reopen the panel (by clicking on Select Device button again), all the device selection that he did earlier shall be lost because to load the panel I'm using sessionStorage proxy store. See the 'example.selectDevices.handleSelectedDevices' function call that loads the panel. For my requirement, I had to PRESERVE user selection.

Comment: @Fabrio : Thanks Fabrio, I was missing the phantom magic! It's working now.